# addEventListener doesn't work for dynamic loading of content

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I want to load buttons dynamically, and every button is loaded with an attached addEventListener and a randomly generated id. the buttons fire an alert.
Problem: when I load (by clicking add button) new buttons, only first button is attached an event listener? here is my code:

```
  <button id="button" type="button" >add</button>
    <div id="demo"></div>



function Pers45on() {
di3=rngc(10,100001);

var yu=document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML;
document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML='<button id="'+di3+'" type="button" >newb</button>'+yu;
document.getElementById(di3).addEventListener('click', al, false);
}

function al(){alert();}

document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function(){Pers45on();}, false);


function rngc(A,B) {
        var d = new Date(),n = d.getMilliseconds();
  return 'ig'+Math.random().toString(36).replace(/[^a-z]+/g, '').substr(0,A)+Math.floor(Math.random() * (B))+n;
}
```

Update: the example code I gave is the same as my actual problem; I am trying to append many HTML elements as a string, and using createElement works fine but is not a solution is not practical. i also have an other solution which works:

```
objar=[];

function Pers45on() {
di3=rngc(10,100001);
objar.push(di3);

var yu=document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML;
document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML='<button id="'+di3+'" type="button" >'+di3+'</button>'+yu;

document.getElementById(di3).addEventListener('click', al, false);

 for(i=0; i<=objar.length;i++){
document.getElementById(objar[i]).addEventListener('click', al, false);
} 

}
```

But I didn't like the for loop, and i am trying to understand why this is happening and looking for any convincing solutions.

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't work? It seems that it should.

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't; I don't know why!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML):

> innerHTML: insert the HTML into the document rather than replace the contents of an element, use the method [insertAdjacentHTML()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML).

Hence, it is enough to change this line:

```
document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML='<button id="'+di3+'" type="button" >newb</button>'+yu;
```

to:

```
document.getElementById('demo').insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<button id="' + di3 + '" type="button" >newb</button>');
```

```js
function Pers45on() {
    di3 = rngc(10, 100001);

    var yu = document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML;
    document.getElementById('demo').insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<button id="' + di3 + '" type="button" >newb</button>');
    document.getElementById(di3).addEventListener('click', al, false);
}

function al() {
    alert();
}

function rngc(A, B) {
    var d = new Date(), n = d.getMilliseconds();
    return 'ig' + Math.random().toString(36).replace(/[^a-z]+/g, '').substr(0, A) + Math.floor(Math.random() * (B)) + n;
}

document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function () {
    Pers45on();
}, false);
```

```html
<button id="button" type="button">add</button>
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: Brilliant piece of info and solution, thanks a lot mate

Answer (score 0):

Your replacing the button instead of appending it. that's the reason it is not working. you can use the appendChild option.

```
function Pers45on() {
    di3 = rngc(10, 100001);

    var yu = document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML;

    var button = document.createElement('button');
    button.setAttribute("id", di3);
    button.innerText="newb"

    document.getElementById('demo').appendChild(button);

    document.getElementById(di3).addEventListener('click', al, false);
}
```

Comment: your answer is good but not practical to my case, please see my update. thanks a lot.